# How do I abstract this pattern in haskell?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads, abstraction

Scenario: I have an interpreter that builds up values bottom-up from an AST. Certain nodes come with permissions -- additional boolean expressions. Permission failures should propagate, but if a node above in the AST comes with a permission, a success can recover the computation and stop the propagation of the error.

At first I thought the `Error MyError MyValue` monad would be enough: one of the members of `MyError` could be `PermError`, and I could use `catchError` to recover from `PermError` if the second check succeeds. However, `MyValue` is gone by the time I get to the handler. I guess there could ultimately be a way of having PermError carry a `MyValue` field so that the handler could restore it, but it would probably be ugly and checking for an exception at each step would defeat the concept of an *exceptional* occurrence.

I'm trying to think of an alternative abstraction. Basically I have to return a datatype `Either AllErrorsExceptPermError (Maybe PermError, MyValue)` or more simply `(Maybe AllErrors, MyValue)` (the other errors are unrecoverable and fit the error monad pretty well) and I'm looking for something that would save me from juggling the tuple around, since there seems to be a common pattern in how the operations are chained. My haskell knowledge only goes so far. How would you use haskell to your advantage in this situation?

While I write this I came up with an idea (SO is a fancy rubber duck): a Monad that that handles internally a type (a, b) (and ultimately returns it when the monadic computation terminates, there has to be some kind of `runMyMonad`), but lets me work with the type b directly as much as possible. Something like

```
data T = Pass | Fail | Nothing
instance Monad (T , b) where
  return v = (Nothing, v)
  (Pass, v) >>= g = let (r', v') = g v in (if r' == Fail then Fail else Pass, v')
  (Fail, v) >>= g = let (r', v') = g v in (if r' == Pass then Pass else Fail, v')
  (Nothing, _) >>= g = error "This should not have been propagated, all chains should start with Pass or Fail"
```

errors have been simplified into T, and the `instance` line probably has a syntax error, but you should get the idea. Does this make sense?

Comment: Why don't you propagate the correct permission information down in the AST, for example by means of `ReaderT Permissions ...`? Then you can always decide locally if the permissions are sufficient.

Comment: I'm not understanding why building an AST needs to be involved with permissions. Why can't you (lazily) build an AST in one step and then run permision calculations on the resulting data structure?

Comment: @kosmikus: because the permissions are expression themselves that need to be evaluated bottom up. missingno: building the AST lazily is step one. step two (the topic of this question) is folding it into a (isAllowed, Value) tuple.

Comment: What you're doing has the flavour of an attribute grammar. Even if you need bottom-up computation for the permissions, you can still write the entire computation as a single traversal over your tree if you want. The type of the value you compute is something like `(Permissions, Permissions -> Value)`. I.e., in every node you assume you get the final permissions as an input and decide how to distribute the permissions downward. On the top, you can apply the bottom-up computed `Permissions` to the function to get the `Value` you're interested in. It's possible to combine this with monads.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `State` monad for permissions and value calculation and wrap that inside `ErrorT` monad transformer to handle the errors. Below is such an example which shows the idea , here the *calculation* is summing up a list, *permissions* are number of even numbers in the list and *error condition* is when we see 0 in the list.

```
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.State

data ZeroError = ZeroError String
              deriving (Show)

instance Error ZeroError where


fun :: [Int] -> ErrorT ZeroError (State Int) Int
fun [] = return 0
fun (0:xs) = throwError $ ZeroError "Zero found"
fun (x:xs) = do
  i <- get
  put $ (if even(x) then i+1 else i)
  z <- fun xs
  return $ x+z


main = f $ runState (runErrorT $ fun [1,2,4,5,10]) 0
       where
         f (Left e,evens) = putStr $ show e
         f (Right r,evens) = putStr $ show (r,evens)
```

Comment: you're right, `State` is an option as well. Problem is, in my limited experience `State` is always an option :D One nice thing I'm learning about Haskell (and I suppose about all strongly typed languages, recovering Python/JS programmer here) is that if you do your due diligence with types and avoid overly generic types, you end up with a type signature with only one possible implementation that typechecks: the correct one :-)

Comment: I'm hesitant to accept this answer, because it is really not what i should be using here. In my case, you have an AST, and unlike your example, the permission can be reverted, but *only* from parents. State would allow siblings to revert decisions. I could add checks, but then the whole point was to enforce this guarantee through the type system. perhaps i should not be using any abstraction at all, having my eval function return a (value, permission) tuple and juggle them manually.